# Battery to AC conversion of faucet IR sensor

Tags: batteries, ac, dc, charger, infrared

I bought [this faucet](https://biobidet.com/products/flow_faucet_up7000bn) which includes a hand IR sensor, but it's battery powered. I wanted to convert it to AC power using [this excellent Video](https://youtu.be/UzruV5pH1RU) as a guide. Since it takes 4 AA batteries, I bought an old Aiwa 6V cell phone charger and followed the instructions to use it as my power source. I wired white to + and black to - and carefully observed the polarities when connecting to the battery compartment.

Upon connecting it, the faucet IR sensor LED started blinking rhythmically and was not responsive to hand gestures. When I replaced the dummy batteries with real ones, it works fine. That is, the LED flashes once with each hand toggle action.

It's probably hard to know why without knowing the specifications for the faucet system, but is there an obvious explanation why my custom power supply would cause the box to respond this way?

[image: 6V AC adapter and dummy battery]

Comment: It could be the voltage is too high (unregulated supply). Or 300ma is not enough for the faucets solenoid. Or your battery socket adapter might be incorrect, depending on the arrangement of the battery compartment.

Comment: Did you actually measure the supply output voltage? That might be an unregulated power supply, and to simulate batteries, stable regulated 6V is needed.

Comment: It could well be ripple voltage on an unregulated supply.

Comment: the cell phone charger may fail in a way that could result in your death

Comment: TIL about regulated supply and its necessity to simulate batteries, thank you. I did measure the voltage at 7V (I attributed the higher voltage to an unloaded measurement). How would I measure if it's unregulated? In any case, I think I should get a regulated supply and test with that. If that solves it, I would be happy to accept an answer to that effect.